# Why ReadWriteLock slower than StampedLock

Tags: java, concurrency

In java 8 StampedLock was added.
StampedLock can serve as ReadWriteLock, but works faster.
The essential reason for this is that it employs some new JVM features(e.g. new memory fencing features).

The question is the following : why ReadWriteLock implementation doesn't employ such features to be as fast as StampedLock(we are talking only about read-write) is.

Benchmarks for different locks : [benchs](https://blog.takipi.com/java-8-stampedlocks-vs-readwritelocks-and-synchronized/)

Comment: Reentrant are often slower due to additional logic to handle them, and it is probably near impossible to change ReadWriteLock without breaking compatibility to make it perform good too, so they decided to add other type of lock that is lower level and allows for better performance.

Comment: `ReadWriteLock` is blocking, with conditionals for wakeup. This is faster for long-running critical sections, like I/O, by descheduling the other threads. `StampedLock` is optimistic by retrying the work when the read is inconsistent. This is faster for short critical sections, like a `Collection` update. However, it does not deschedule threads and this can cause busy waiting overhead (burning CPU cycles). Most often neither should be used and an exclusive lock is simpler and faster.